# Adjective for tax to use in "from a tax standpoint"

Tags: adjectives

Is there any adjective for tax one could use in the phrase "from a tax standpoint"?

In French I would say "from a fiscal standpoint" but I don't see the expression in the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fiscal+standpoint&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and looking at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fiscal, "fiscal" seems to typically means "relating to government finance/revenues". This makes me wonder whether the meaning of "fiscal" has shifted between its meaning in French (where it clearly means tax-related) and its meaning in English.

Example where I'd like to use of "from a tax standpoint": [How do some companies allow some of/all their employees to work remotely from a tax standpoint?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/126132/5656)

Comment: We say in English: from a tax standpoint. tax can be a noun or an adjective. I am a financial translator (French<English) et je peux vous l'assurer.... we also use: tax-wise or from the point of view of taxes.

Comment: @Lambie awesome, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Oh, another detail, we do say fiscal year or tax year in the States So,année fiscale. It can get hairy, all this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internet throws up *taxative* and *taxational*, but in terms of common use and understanding, I'd say "tax standpoint" would be more likely, even if it's technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful contribution.

Comment: Perhaps you need to refresh yourself on the meaning of the word "if".

Comment: You say: tax standpoint, [[even it it's technically incorrect]]. It is not technically incorrect at all. **You were right say we say tax standpoint** and it is *technically correct*.

Comment: I made two claims in my sentence.  Firstly that the internet suggests taxative and taxational as adjective forms relating to tax, which it does.  And secondly, that regardless of what is the technically correct choice, the most commonly used and understood option would be simply "tax", which it is.  Don't turn up declaring posts "totally incorrect" when 2/2 of the claims made therein are not incorrect.

Comment: You are twisting my words. **I never said that tax standpoint is wrong. I said it was right**. And ask why you even say: "even if it's technically incorrect"?? Of course, it isn't technically incorrect. You should edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To support [stevekeiretsu](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/107915/stevekeiretsu)'s [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/249258/3023), I see [on the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200719223907/https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements)):

> Unmarried individual (or married filing separately): Total value of assets was more than $50,000 on the last day of the **tax year**, or more than $75,000 at any time during the year.

As a result, it indeed seems ok to use "tax" as as adjective.

Comment: Yes, the French word fiscale is tax in English. la fiscalité = taxation, la situation fscale =the tax situation